# How to make sense of the EM algorithm expressed in terms of Kullback-Leibler divergence?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, expectation-maximization

In the textbook *All of Statistics* by Wasserman, the algorithm is expressed as:

1. Pick a starting value $\theta^0$.
2. (E-Step). Calculate:

   $$
   J(\theta|\theta^j) = E_{\theta^j} \left(\log \dfrac{f(Y^n, Z^n;\theta)}{f(Y^n, Z^n;\theta^j)}\bigg| Y^n = y^n\right)
   $$

   where the expectation is over the missing data $Z^n$ treating $\theta_i$ and the observed data $Y^n$ as fixed.
3. Find $\theta^{j+1}$ to maximize $J(\theta\mid \theta^j)$.

My confusion here is regarding why we have a ratio here. Normally how I derive it is to start with the fundamental identity:

$$
f(Y,Z|\theta) = f(Z|Y, \theta)f(Y|\theta)
$$
implies that
$$
f(Y|\theta) = \frac{f(Y,Z|\theta)}{f(Z|Y, \theta)}
$$

Taking logs:

$$
l(\theta|Y) = l(\theta|Y,Z) - \log(f(Z|Y,\theta))
$$

Taking expectations:

$$
l(\theta|Y) = E_{Z|\theta^{(t)}}\left[l(\theta|Y,Z)|Y\right] - E_{Z|\theta^{(t)}}\left[\log(f(Z|Y,\theta))|Y\right]
$$

Then, we want to maximize the second term: $E_{Z|\theta^{(t)}}\left[l\left(\theta|Y,Z\right)|Y\right]$ with respect to $\theta$.

I am not able to reconcile these two definitions. Would someone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't read book, my guess is as follows. Since EM maximizes the lower bound 
$$l(\theta|Y)=E_{q(Z)}[\log\frac{p(Y,Z|\theta)}{q(Z)}]$$
In the E step we set $q(Z)$ to be $p(Z|Y,\theta_0)$, the lower bound becomes
$$l(\theta|Y)=E_{p(Z|Y,\theta_0)}[\log\frac{p(Y,Z|\theta)}{p(Z|Y,\theta_0)}]$$
$$=E_{p(Z|Y,\theta_0)}[\log\frac{p(Y,Z|\theta)}{p(Y,Z|\theta_0)/p(Y|\theta_0)}]$$
since $p(Y|\theta_0)$ doesn't depend on $Z$ it can be taken out of the expectation
$$l(\theta|Y)=\log p(Y|\theta_0)E_{p(Z|Y,\theta_0)}[\log\frac{p(Y,Z|\theta)}{p(Y,Z|\theta_0)}]$$
and $p(Y|\theta_0)$ also doesn't depend on $\theta$ in the subsequent M step so it can be ignored, then we have the same from as in the book
$$l(\theta|Y)=E_{p(Z|Y,\theta_0)}[\log\frac{p(Y,Z|\theta)}{p(Y,Z|\theta_0)}]$$